# Incrementing a field value over time in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I am fairly new to databases and DBMS. I have a table in which there are multiples Integer fields. `Number(3,0)`

Is there a way to increment (+1) each ones of those fields over time with PL/SQL (automatic)?

For example, I have the field `TEST(Number(3,0))` in my table and I want its value to increment by one for every hour that passes.

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen when the value gets too large for NUMBER(3,0) after 999 hours? What are you trying to achieve? Why not just use a DATE and record SYSDATE or CURRENT_DATE in it and then simply calculate the difference in hours between SYSDATE/CURRENT_DATE and the field value when you want to know how many hours have passed?

Comment: It's for a little game, I want every user to get one extra coin in their accounts for every day/hour that passes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's for a little game, I want every user to get one extra coin in their accounts for every day/hour that passes

You could create job to do it:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'give_gold',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN UPDATE tab_name SET gold_val = gold_val+1; END;',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0',
    end_date        => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE,
    comments        => 'This job gives +1 gold every hour');
```

Of course you could fire stored procedure and make complex calculations. More info: **[DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)**

Comment: Thank you lad ! That's exactly what I was looking for !